# How to use insert all method including associations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems

I have Article, Category and CategoryArticle models

```
# models/article.rb
Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category_articles
  has_many :categories, through: :category_articles
end

# models/category.rb
Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category_articles
  has_many :articles, through: :category_articles
end

# models/category.rb
CategoryArticle < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :article
end
```

What I'd like to do is insert a collection of articles with their respective categories, such as:

```
article = Article.new
article.created_at = Time.zone.now
article.updated_at = Time.zone.now

article_collection = []
article_collection << article.as_json(:except => :id)       

Article.insert_all(article)
```

The code above works for me, but when I want to insert the association I get an error like:

unknown keyword:: categories

Because I'm inserting a whole collection from a json and it does not recognize categories as attribute

Ultimately, the following works:

```
irb(main):029:0> article_collection
=> 
[{"id"=>nil,
  "name"=>"example",
  "created_at"=>"2021-11-05T22:19:55.850Z",
  "updated_at"=>"2021-11-05T22:20:05.481Z"}]
```

Article.insert_all(article)

but this does not work when I want to install the category collection:

```
  irb(main):029:0> article_collection
  => 
  [{"id"=>nil,
   "name"=>"example",
   "created_at"=>"2021-11-05T22:19:55.850Z",
   "updated_at"=>"2021-11-05T22:20:05.481Z",
   "categories"=>[{"id"=>1, "name"=>"Whisky", "created_at"=>"2021-11- 
                   05T18:07:05.737Z",  "updated_at"=>"2021-11-05T18:07:05.737Z"}]}]

Article.insert_all(article)
=> unknown attribute 'categories' for Article
```

If you could tell me how to use insert_all for a multiple association I would be grateful

Comment: Try setting `accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories` in the Article class and rename the `categories` key as `categories_attributes` in the hash with the data, that way rails should know how to handle the association https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: If it works for me but when executing the insert_all or upsert_all methods it does not recognize the categories_attributte

And how do I need it to do many inserts in a single query

Comment: I just noticed that categories is a has_many through association, not a simple has_many, I don't think you can do what you want in 1 insert. I would split this into first saving all the categories and then saving all the articles using a `categories_ids` key with all the categories ids, I think that way it could work

Comment: I'm going to try, thank you very much for your time: D

Answer (score 4):

`insert_all` and `update_all` and `destroy_all` etc. Do not work as other methods you might expect on a Active Record instance. Because they designed for bulk operations no instances of the model are created the arguments you pass are just reduced directly to *a single SQL INSERT statement*. https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods/insert_all

This means lots of things you might expect to work will not work, e.g. no observers or events (e.g. no `after_create` `after_save` are fired with an insert_all. `accept_nested_attributes` cannot work in this picture, there is no way they can reduce to a single SQL INSERT statement.

So I would suggest using `create` for this purpose.